# Can I change stringformat after binding

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I am trying to create a custom textbox that extends the default textbox "TextBoxEx : TextBox"
The goal is to have the input formatting at one place while writing as little binding code as possible.

```
<local:TextBoxEx Text="{Binding ADateWithValue}" TextType="Date" />
```

If it's possible I would like to get the bound data type and set a sensible default format.

I know that the binding once created is immutable, but there has to be a way to set a converter, stringformat or hook into the process in some clever way, maybe using OverrideMetadata?

Comment: Why create a custom control for this and not using valueconverters?

Comment: I would have to agree with @RalfdeKleine... hiding the `StringFormat` is only going to confuse other developers and/or make your code harder to read.

Comment: I just think that its easier to have all input format in one package.